# polygon is displaying in very smallersize

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am drawing polygon from existing lonlats. But it is showing in very very smaller size.
Code is as follows,

```
for(var i in coordinates) {
  point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(coordinates.lon,coordinates.lat);
  point.transform(new OpenLayers.projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());
  points.push(point);
}
points.push(points[0]);
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]),null,{strokeColor:"black",
fillColor:"orange",sides:4});
newLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
newLayer.redraw(true);
```

But it is displaying in very very small size .
How to show in bigger size? Any help?

Comment: I was confused by `sides` which is not an option of OpenLayers.Feature.Vector, the small size defined by your coordinates, you should check if coordinates was transformed correct on your map

Comment: ok if i remove sides and if i set radius , then also its showing in the same way

Comment: yes, radius will not work, that why i deleted answer, i think coordinates wrong, or point.transform() do not expected result, if you could make fiddle i can check more

Comment: i  found that [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/copystar/reKRr/1/) he uses 
`myPoint = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(bridgeview_long, bridgeview_lat).transform( map.displayProjection,  map.projection);`
so it may turn that you need to use 
`point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(coordinates.lon,coordinates.lat).transform(new OpenLayers.projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());
  `

Comment: or
`point=point.transform(new OpenLayers.projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point.transform() not change `point` object itself, it returns new `point`,so:
also here is no index (`i`) used in loop, plus here was syntax error (`new OpenLayers.projection` should be `new OpenLayers.Projection`

```
for(var i in coordinates) {
  point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(coordinates[i].lon,coordinates[i].lat);
  points.push(
         point.transform(
             new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
             map.getProjectionObject()
         )
  );
}
points.push(points[0]);
var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(points);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
  new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]),null,{
    strokeColor:"black", 
    fillColor:"orange",
    });
newLayer.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
newLayer.redraw(true);
```

[working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/23cGb/) - note a pretty big orange rectangle in africa

Comment: I tried in this way also.. no change.. i am  getting the same result

Comment: lol, i found mistake, it is to simple, you not used index in loop